# Can you arrest a person without police?

Tags: united-kingdom, police, arrest, citizens-arrest

Is it possible to make the decision of arresting a person that is not judged by the police. For example by someone trained in law, like a lawyer.

It is not uncommon to get some form of police corruption or the ranks may close up on you. I know of at least two cases where the police will not arrest individuals that they know are involved in crime:

1. In Project Sanctuary, the mole idenified many judges, police cheifs, etc... involved in child grooming

see: https://brightfuturesne.co.uk/programmes/project-sanctuary/

2. I know someone protesting for justice against police.

Can the question be based on UK law.

This is not so much so a question on normal citizens arrest where for example you catch a shoplifter then wait for the police to arrest them, but rather you catch the person having all necessary evidence then try them in court by-passing the police altogether.

Comment: Your edit has changed the thread's topic from citizen's arrest to whether one can bring a private prosecution which makes the answer and comments look incorrect. You may wish to consider asking a new question (especially as this one is closed).

Answer (score 0):

Depends on where you are, and on the situation.

Many countries allow citizens to detain a suspect, this is called a [citizen's arrest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Citizen%27s_arrest) even if it may not technically be an arrest. Usually the citizens are required to deliver the suspect to the *real* police, and they may be limited to situations where they witnessed a suspected crime. If there *is* time to go through proper channels, citizens are supposed to go through proper channels.

Comment: I know the UK also has some pretty strong "Shop Keeper's Privilege" Laws on the books, which is a subset of citizen's arrest that protects shop keepers in allowing them to detain possible shop lifters until police can search the suspect.

Comment: I have edited the question somewhat as it is miss-understood. The doublicate question that the StackExchanger has proposed does not seem to ansewer my question, though iIhave read only the top ansewer.